# What is the best way to precompile EmberJS templates on Windows

Tags: windows, templates, ember.js, precompile

I'm trying to determine the best way to precompile EmberJS templates using Windows and can't seem to find any good options.

Can anyone recommend a good proven solution?

I'm using Ember v 1.10.0

EDIT:
I have installed the latest version of NodeJS and followed the instructions from here: http://www.ember-cli.com/#getting-started.

For the record, I am using Windows 8.1 running on a Surface Pro 2.

I have tried installing Ember CLI using NodeJs and I get the following error(s):

```
C:\>npm install -g ember-cli
npm WARN engine makeerror@1.0.10: wanted: {"node":"0.6.x"} (current: {"node":"0.
12.0","npm":"2.5.1"})
npm WARN engine tmpl@1.0.3: wanted: {"node":"0.6.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.0",
"npm":"2.5.1"})
C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\ember -> C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm
\node_modules\ember-cli\bin\ember
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ember-cli"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package handlebars does not satisfy its siblings' peerD
ependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer ember-template-compiler@1.8.0 wants handlebars@~1
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ember-cli"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1

npm ERR! Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends what tools/frameworks you are using:

1. If you are using [Ember CLI](http://www.ember-cli.com/) (and I'd strongly recommend it), it is able to precompile your templates directly from the command line (and much more). It's a bit slower on Windows that Unix systems (due to symlink issues on Windows) but the Ember team is working on it. I personally use Ember CLI both on Windows and Linux Debian for my own projects and it works great.
2. If you do not want to use Ember CLI for now and work with .Net you can use [csharp-ember-handlebars](https://github.com/Myslik/csharp-ember-handlebars) within an ASP.Net MVC project. Note that in this case, the precompilation of your templates will happen when the server is started via the [ASP.Net MVC bundling mechanism](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification).
3. If you just want to compile templates outside of any framework then you could install Node.js and use the [node-ember-precompile](https://github.com/gabrielgrant/node-ember-precompile) package. This is probably the most tedious way but could be automated using Grunt or Gulp.

In general, no matter what you use on the server (Node, Rails, Python, .Net, Java, ...) you will always find a server-side library to handle your templates precompilation.

I would still recommend working with Ember CLI if possible (since this is the future of Ember, and not only for the build), then deploy your precompiled templates directly behind IIS, Apache or (even better) Nginx.

Let me know if you need more details for a specific environment.

Comment: Hi and thanks for commenting.  I'm happy to use Ember CLI and have tried installing it but I get errors.  Please see the addition to the question for more details.  I hope you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: I'd suggest reinstalling node and npm at this point. The `wanted: {"node":"0.6.x"}` does not make any sense it's a very old version.